# When are powershell related questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003540/powershell-use-multiple-predetermined-arguments?noredirect=1#comment1304606_1003540) I was asking something about Powershell syntax - I had a specific problem with the Powershell commands of Microsoft Exchange server, but wanted to know the answer for all kinds of Powershell commandlets.

I was then informed that this question could be off-topic. Quote:

> Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Your question "*… is not Exchange specific, I want to know if Powershell can handle …*" Blatantly off-topic being about common Powershell features.

Of course Powershell is available on every Windows computer, but I honestly think that most people use it for business-related things. I do a lot with powershell here at work, but at home I use it twice a month...

So are Powershell questions off-topic at ServerFault? If so, there are [many high-voted Powershell questions that have nothing to do with Enterprise applications](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/powershell?tab=Votes).

Where is the (I think thin) line between off and on-topic when it comes to Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually [powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/powershell) questions are on-topic as [powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/powershell) is an important tool for Windows Sysadmin.

Now for for your question;

At the time I wrote that, I don't see any close vote casted for it, so it seem good, but the user that left you a comment is not wrong too there but for another reason IMO. It could be seen as a learning recommendation the way it's wrote.

In example if you had a problem in your Exchange 2013 and you need to create a complex script and you need to pass two values to the commandlet but it doesn't work in your case, that would be more on topic than just a generic question on how to get two parameters.

I told it as I see two questions inside your question;

1) Short version: is it possible to pass multiple predefined arguments to a powershell function/commandlet?

2) The Get-MoveRequest documentation does not state if or if not the MoveStatus parameter allows multiple values as argument.

So, if you need to script the Get-MoveRequest to get multiple value, and it doesn't work, it's really on topic for your question #2 (and you can do copy/paste of what you tried). A generic question about your question #1 could be closed with that reason;

> Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations
>   are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam
>   answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. **Instead, describe
>   the business problem you are working on, the research you have done,
>   and the steps taken so far to solve it.**

I put in bold the part that I try to explain, that if you have a problem and try to understand how to use powershell to solve it, please state the exact problem and what you have tried, it's the better way to get an answer

Again, I dont see any close vote yet as you have wrote your question on a grey line, I would suggest to edit to show what you tried, and why you look for that information.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I am struggeling with two things: at first, my first question was describing a specific problem with my exchange - and I thought the answer was not exchange specific but for all Powershell commands. Second, if a question about how to use Powershell commands is off topic here - is there any site where it is on-topic?